# вывод компонентов reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

Прохожу курс "Основы React.js", 9 часть - "Жизненный цикл React-компонентов"(1 мин 30 сек). Вопрос следующий: имеется два компонента article и ArticleList. Первый представляет статью ,  а второй вывод всех статей. Стоит задача при выводе статей открыть только первую статью, автор добавляет параметр index и передает значение в параметр deafultOpen = {index === 0}и получается при загрузке страницы открывается только первая статья , остальные закрыты (Код приведу ниже). Откуда параметр index берет значение чтобы сравнить его с 0? Или каким образом работает вся эта система?

```js
// Статья
class Article extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state={
            modeClose: props.defaultOpen
        }
    }
    onHandle = () => {
        console.log('Clicked');
        this.setState({
            modeClose: !this.state.modeClose
        })
    }
    render() {
        const {article} = this.props;
        const body = this.state.modeClose && <section className="card-text">{article.text}</section>;
        return (
            <div className="card mx-auto" style={{}}>
                <div className="card-header">
                <h2 className="d-inline-block">{article.title}</h2>
                <button onClick={this.onHandle} className="btn btn-primary btn-lg float-right">Close</button>
                </div>
                <div className="card-body">
                    <h6 className="text-muted card-text"> creation date: {(new Date(article.date)).toDateString()}</h6>
                    {body}
                </div>
                </div>
        )
    }
}

//Вывод компонента ArticleList
export default function articleList({articles}){
    const artcileElements = articles.map((article,index) => <li className="article-list__li" key={article.id}><Article article= {article} defaultOpen= {index=== 0} /></li> )
    return <ul>
        {artcileElements}
    </ul>
}
```

Comment: index - это ключи массива articles, соответственно первый элемент будет articles[0], т.е. index=0

Comment: @DmitryKozlov Оформишь в ответ?

Answer (score 0):

> Метод map() создаёт новый массив с результатом вызова указанной функции для каждого элемента массива.
>
> Функция, создающая элемент в новом массиве, принимает три аргумента:
>
> - **currentValue** Текущий обрабатываемый элемент массива.
> - **index** Индекс текущего обрабатываемого элемента в массиве.
> - **array** Массив, по которому осуществляется проход.
>
> [Справка](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Поскольку индексы элементов массива нумеруются, начиная с `0`, то при первой итерации переменная `index` примет значение `0` и проверка `{index=== 0}` даст результат `true`